# What is the name of the "clicky" t sound used in some british accents in words like "little" and "mental"?

Tags: english, phonetics, ipa

Emma Stone tries to replicate it [here](https://youtu.be/36FdXGaDsaE?t=21).

It's not a glottal stop; the t is definitely being pronounced in the mouth and not the throat. It's almost exclusively used when a "t" sound is immediately followed by an "l" sound. Bottle, little, mental.

When I try to reproduce it, I'm using my full tongue to seal the top of my mouth, letting a bit of air fill that pocket and then -- leaving the front of my tongue pressed against the alveolar ridge -- letting the air pop out of the sides of my tongue to create a "click." Come to think of it, the speakers who pronounce "tl" this way also produce a similar sound for the "cl" of words like "click" itself.

Comment: I don't hear any clicky sound. Tle is common in English.

Comment: I'm aware, but there is a distinctly British way to pronounce it. user6726 had what I was looking for. Here's a native British English speaker going over the difference: https://www.youtube.com/live/b0rHMFly7_4?t=2439&si=VyJEh_XiT8vqYjXf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what's known as a lateral release, transcribed as [tˡ].

Comment: That's it! Oh my god, I was going crazy looking for this. Thanks very much :)